# Salable Quantity is showing zero in product grid magento 2?

Tags: magento2, quantity, magento2.3, product-grid

Actually in my case **Salable Quantity** is showing **zero** in product grid **Magento 2.3**.

Due to this issue, products are not showing in frontend. If anyone has any idea then please tell me.

For this re-indexing is also done but still **Salable Quantity** is showing **zero**(0).

Add and update Quantity programmatic but **Salable Quantity** is showing **zero** .

Comment: try to allow out of stock backorder and check if the products will be displayed. This is not a fix but at least to check wether the exact problem is the salable qty.

Comment: have you fixed it?

Comment: yes actually there was a permission problem in our server

Comment: Hi, Have you found out the issue?

Comment: @Octopus,yes reindex worked always but there was permission in server then it is resolved

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunately, reindex doesn't solve this issue

Comment: Reindexing "cataloginventory_stock" and "inventory" ids resolve this issue.

Comment: So I experienced this problem while running a demo Magento 2.3 site on localhost. When I added new products, they'd have a default stock of zero. To eliminate this problem, I had to run `php bin\magento indexer:reindex`. Seems like it was a problem relating to Magento not indexing properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162685)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162685)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162685)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**In DataBase, There was two type,**

1. **Tables**
2. **Views**

The issue is possibly caused when Import/Export DataBase **Views** was not created in Magento 2.3. So create **Views** and  **inventory_stock_1** table in DataBase.

See Attached Image:

[image]

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`))) ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After spending 2 hours I got the solutions from your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Savan its already created at my end. but still facing same issue

Comment: @insoftservice I am facing the same issue, did you get any idea?

Comment: @HardikVisa do you have this view at your end. If yes just try to execute it manually at my end it was given permission issue which got resolved by granting full permission.

Answer (score 17):

I'm gonna share my experience related to this issue, I hope it could help someone who would have been in the same situation.

We were working on a staged instance, All was ready to go to production.
So we duplicated everything on the prod env and launched some **SQL truncates** in order to delete every dummy Orders, Reviews, etc.. you get the idea.

After some final tests, **We realized that our products "stock qty" were far different from product "salable qty"**.

The SQL View seemed to work fine, So we investigated deeper. Turns out we missed a SQL table in our truncate instructions :

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `inventory_reservation`;
```

This bad girl was containing each "**not shipped but reserved products**" from past orders.

Of course, don't forget to reindex stuff :

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. I was struggling to remove negative salable quantity.

Comment: What will happen if there are current orders in production. Will re-indexing reduce the default stock for other items in orders after truncating the table?

Comment: In my case, I just run indexer command and QTY started showing perfectly!!! Thanks +1 , made my day :)

Answer (score 11):

I skipped this line of query, due to Previllages error and my add to cart was not working on live server, in local server this line was not skipped and add to cart was working fine.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`))) ;
```

Because the View was not created in the live server
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had to remove the `DEFINER=`root`@`localhost from @Thakur answer so here is what I used:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS
select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
`product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product`
on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`))) ;
```

Failure to remove it caused a privilege error.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below steps:

```
Admin -> Stores -> Inventory -> Stock -> Edit Default Stock -> Sales Channels -> select Main Website
```

It worked fine.

OR find the below link

https://webkul.com/blog/get-salable-quantity-in-magento-2-3/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, after creating the view by executing the below query my problem has been resolved.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`{database_user_name}`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1`  AS  
    SELECT distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
        `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
        `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
        `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
        `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
        `product`.`sku` AS `sku` 
   FROM
   (
         `cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` 
              join `catalog_product_entity` `product` 
                  on ((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`))
   ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to fix this would be to remove the patch from the `patch_list` and re-run the `setup:upgrade` to re-invoke the command.

The code responsible for creating the `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` can be found in 
Magento\InventoryCatalog\Setup\Patch\Schema\CreateLegacyStockStatusView.

You can remove the data patch from the patch list by searching running

`select * from patch_list where patch_name = 'Magento\InventoryCatalog\Setup\Patch\Schema\CreateLegacyStockStatusView`

Delete the record.

Re-run 
`setup:upgrade`
`setup:di:compile`
`setup:static-content:deploy`

Re-save the products with **ZERO Salable Quantity** either one by one or mass action via admin.

Answer (score -10):

I just changed to  STORE -> CATELOG -> INVENTORY -> PRODUCTS STOCK OPTIONS -> BACKORDERS -> Allow Qty Below 0

and the issue solved

Comment: That's not what back order meant to be used for.