# Can't set product's stock - default stock: 0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, out-of-stock, stock-availability

I have issue on Magento 2.3.2 - Every product I add has *Salable Quantity -- Default Stock: 0* -- therefore all the time out of stock.

It happens to every product I add. I tried reindexing, clearing cache, going into production mode, setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile.

Any suggestions please?

[image: Salable Quantity is always set to 0]

Comment: Hope this link will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256997/salable-quantity-is-showing-zero-in-product-grid-magento-2

Comment: Actually - Just out of curiosity I've removed the table inventory_stock_1 and re-added it with the query from second answer and works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then i have created e new Sources (Stores -> Inventory -> Sources) and assigned the new source to the product (Product -> Sources -> Assign Sources). It's not the best solution, but it works and maybe you can start from there.

Update: i was able to make it work by changing the "website_id" from 1 to 0 in the "cataloginventory_stock" table.