# Magento2 Salable Qty value is not correct how can we re-calculate this value? List inconsistencies? Fix it?

Tags: magento2, msi, reservations

Salable Qty <> sum(sources)

No idea why. We are testing MSI and Backorders and have use the Ampersand extension to disable reservations. But nonetheless: how can salable qty be incorrect? and more importantly how can we force the system to recalculate it? ore reset it?

**Question**: Magento2 Salable Qty value is not correct how can we re-calculate this value? List inconsistencies? Fix it?

[image]

https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation

Comment: please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256997/salable-quantity-is-showing-zero-in-product-grid-magento-2

Comment: Thanks saw that. But that’s not a fix for the absurd situation where the value is not in sync. There should be some

Comment: Kind of recalculation button or method

Answer (score 0):

You can check reservations inconsistencies with a command

```
php bin/magento inventory:reservation:list-inconsistencies
```

To compensate reservation manually

```
php bin/magento inventory:reservation:create-compensations
```

To prevent new reservations from being created, on the admin menu, tap Stores → Settings → Configuration, select Catalog → Inventory → Stock Options → Decrease Stock When Order → No.

All reservations are stored in `inventory_reservation` database table.

Comment: But there is not batch process that does this? In our M1 solution there was a watcher process that check for inconsistencies-every quarter or so there were 3 maybe 4 inconsistencies and we had to click the button and magento would recalculate all and make it sound again.