# Confusion around Salable Quantity

Tags: magento2, stock, stock-availability

Can anyone explain what salable quantity is and how do you change it?

Each time I change the stock quantity the salable quantity changes too. I don't understand why.

[image]

salable quantity seems to be 4, when I change stock to 2 salable quantity goes to -2.

[image]

On the product page it is not editable.

[image]

Any tips or explanation would be much appreciated. I've gone through the docs but I cant seem to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the below link to understand the concept of salable qty and qty

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Explanation-for-Default-stock-and-Salable-Qty/td-p/321304

[Salable Quantity is showing zero in product grid magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256997/salable-quantity-is-showing-zero-in-product-grid-magento-2)