# how to display the Salable Quantity section in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I encountered this after reinstalling something in the admin of magento2. How can the Salable Quantity section be displayed, please help me to solve it. thank you.

[image]

Comment: please run reindex command($ bin/magento indexer:reindex).
is this not work then i tell you other solution.

Comment: it is not working please help me find another solution

Comment: Follow this step and check in database.
[Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256997/salable-quantity-is-showing-zero-in-product-grid-magento-2)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will learn more about it